# How do I specify the time resolution in Cocotb?

Tags: verification, modelsim, cocotb

I am getting a different clock period, when I am simulating the [Endian Swapper](http://cocotb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/endian_swapper.html) example of Cocotb in VHDL and Verilog mode using QuestaSim. The clock is generated in the same way for both modes in the [provided example code](https://github.com/potentialventures/cocotb/blob/master/examples/endian_swapper/tests/test_endian_swapper.py):

```py
@cocotb.coroutine
def clock_gen(signal):
    while True:
        signal <= 0
        yield Timer(5000)
        signal <= 1
        yield Timer(5000)


@cocotb.coroutine
def run_test(dut): # stripped un

    cocotb.fork(clock_gen(dut.clk))
```

When running in Verilog mode with:

```
make SIM=questa GUI=1
```

the clock period is 1000 ns (**one** thousand nano-seconds), and thus, the time resolution is 100 ps.

When running in VHDL mode with:

```
make SIM=questa GUI=1 TOPLEVEL_LANG=vhdl
```

the clock period is 10000 ns (**ten** thousand nano-seconds), and thus, the time resolution is 1 ns.

I am using the same clock generation in two other VHDL projects. In one I am getting a clock period of 10000 ns too, (1 ns resolution). But in the other one, the clock period is only 10 ns, giving a resolution of 1 ps.

Why differs the time resolution in all these run modes and projects?

How do I specifiy the time resolution consistently?

Comment: Worth noting there is a `cocotb.clock.Clock` class for convenience, which saves having to repeatedly define a `clock_gen` coroutine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No time resolution is specified for the `vsim` command within the `runsim.do` file generated by the Makefiles. Thus, the default time resolution of the simulator is used as specified in the `modelsim.ini`. One of the other VHDL projects had a private `modelsim.ini` with a time resolution set to 1 ps (`Resolution = ps`) instead of the default 1 ns (`Resolution = ns`).

Additional `vsim` arguments can be specified by the Makefile variable `VSIM_ARGS` of the Cocotb build system. But setting this variable on the command line with:

```
make SIM=questa GUI=1 "VSIM_ARGS=-t 1ps"
```

does not work as expected because other required `vsim` arguments have now been stripped of.

One has to set this variable in the project-specific Makefile instead, e.g., just before including the system-wide Makefiles:

```
VSIM_ARGS=-t 1ps

include $(COCOTB)/makefiles/Makefile.inc
include $(COCOTB)/makefiles/Makefile.sim
```

This way, one gets a consistent time resolution across VHDL and Verilog. The parameter has to be set for every project accordingly.

Comment: See also [issue 115](https://github.com/potentialventures/cocotb/issues/115) where we discuss defining time in absolute units, which would solve this at the Python level.  After [#383](https://github.com/potentialventures/cocotb/pull/383) was merged we know the absolute time precision so defining timers in terms of units shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: @Chiggs Regarding issue #383, is there already a Python function to call `vhpi_get_phys(vhpiResolutionLimitP, NULL)`? I didn't find one in the sources.

Answer (score 2):

Since [cocotb 1.3.0](https://docs.cocotb.org/en/stable/release_notes.html#cocotb-1-3-0), you can use [COCOTB_HDL_TIMEUNIT](https://docs.cocotb.org/en/stable/building.html#var-COCOTB_HDL_TIMEUNIT) and [COCOTB_HDL_TIMEPRECISION](https://docs.cocotb.org/en/stable/building.html#var-COCOTB_HDL_TIMEPRECISION) makefile variables to define timescale in a simulator agnostic way.